# How can I display the `lastLogn` for a user in my list view from Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory

In my Windows Forms App I have a radio button that when selected it display's the user's First Names, Last Names and Usernames by using this code:

```
 if (rdbUsers.Checked == true)
        {
            string strADPath = txtLDAP.Text.ToString();
            string strUsername = txtUsername.Text.ToString();
            string strPassword = txtPassword.Text.ToString();
            try
            {
                lstActiveDirectory.Clear();
                lstActiveDirectory.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
                lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("First Name", 150);
                lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Name", 150);
                lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Logon Name", 150);
                using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strADPath, strUsername, strPassword))
                {
                    using (var searcher = new PrincipalSearcher(new UserPrincipal(context)))
                    {
                        foreach (var result in searcher.FindAll())
                        {
                            DirectoryEntry de = result.GetUnderlyingObject() as DirectoryEntry;
                            string[] arr = new string[3];
                            ListViewItem itm;

                            //Add first item
                            arr[0] = (string)de.Properties["givenName"].Value;
                            arr[1] = (string)de.Properties["sn"].Value;
                            arr[2] = (string)de.Properties["samAccountName"].Value;
                            itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                            lstActiveDirectory.Items.Add(itm);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                rdbUsers.Checked = false;
                lstActiveDirectory.Clear();
            }
        }
```

This works great and is displayed correctly in my `ListView` ie.

```
|  First Name     |  Last Name   |  Username   |
------------------------------------------------
|  User           |  user        |  userlogon  |
```

So now what I would like to do is display the `lastLogon` for each of the users.  So I modified my code with the following:

1. Added the Column

   lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Logon", 150);
2. Added the `Property` to load

   arr[3] = de.Properties["LastLogon"].ToString();

Then tested again.  What I am getting now is the following:

```
|  First Name     |  Last Name   |  Username   |  Last Logon                                 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  User           |  user        |  userlogon  |  System.DirectoryServices.PropertyValueCollection
```

When I change the code to:

```
arr[3] = de.Properties["LastLogon"].Value.ToString();
```

I get the following error:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

At that modified code

Not sure what I can do now to correct his and to display the last logon for each user?

Thanks

**EDIT**

This code is working as expected but not displaying the correct `lastLogon` but rather the `lastLogonTimeStamp`

```
 if (rdbUsers.Checked == true)
        {
            string strADPath = txtLDAP.Text.ToString();
            string strUsername = txtUsername.Text.ToString();
            string strPassword = txtPassword.Text.ToString();
            try
            {
                using (PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strADPath))
                {
                    if (context.ValidateCredentials(strUsername, strPassword))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            lstActiveDirectory.Clear();
                            lstActiveDirectory.Sorting = SortOrder.Ascending;
                            lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("First Name", 150);
                            lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Name", 150);
                            lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Logon", 150);
                            lstActiveDirectory.Columns.Add("Last Password Reset", 150);
                            DirectoryEntry objDirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(strADPath, strUsername, strPassword);

                            PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, strADPath, strUsername, strPassword);
                            UserPrincipal usr = new UserPrincipal(ctx);
                            PrincipalSearcher ps = new PrincipalSearcher(usr);
                            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> results = ps.FindAll();

                            foreach (UserPrincipal u in results)
                            {
                                string[] arr = new string[4];
                                ListViewItem itm;

                                //Add first item
                                arr[0] = u.DisplayName;
                                arr[1] = u.SamAccountName;
                                arr[2] = u.LastLogon.ToString();
                                arr[3] = u.LastPasswordSet.ToString();
                                itm = new ListViewItem(arr);
                                lstActiveDirectory.Items.Add(itm);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Please Login First!");
                            rdbUsers.Checked = false;
                            lstActiveDirectory.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Incorrect Server, Username Or Password");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                rdbUsers.Checked = false;
                lstActiveDirectory.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can I point out that the other properties seem to be camelCased, whereas you're trying to use "LastLogon". I'm guessing that `PropertyValueCollection` is case sensitive.

Comment: Hi, thanks,  I have tried to use `lastLogon` and still giving me the same error (if that's what you are referring to?)

Comment: That's what I was wondering about. Have you verified that the property exists in `de.Properties` using the debugger?

Comment: Hi, Okay I see what you mean.  I saw what mistake I made.  I have edited my original question with the new code.  It shows the `lastLogon` and have also added `lastPasswordSet`  But it is not showing the correct `lastLogon`.  So effectively it shows the `lastLogonTimestamp` instead of the `lastLogon` as per Active Directory attribut editor